# C-style struct in Objc not importing to Swift

Tags: c, objective-c, swift, struct, bridging-header

The problem I'm encountering, and absolutely not understanding, is why can my Swift code not access an bridged C-style struct import from objective-c when a `NSString` pointer is contained, whereas the struct is visible when then `NSString` is replaced with a `char *`.

For example, when I've got the following defined in my `Foo.h` file:

```
typedef struct {
    NSString* value;
    SomeEnum unit;
} SomeMeasurement;
```

I get an error of `Value of Type ... has no member Measurement` (from the parental `class`) at compile time.

Whereas when my struct is the following:

```
typedef struct {
    char* value;
    SomeEnum unit;
} SomeMeasurement;
```

Things compile as expected (even if `char` unusable for my current needs).
The fact that that small change allows for this struct to be "seen" by Swift is totally perplexing me, since it means it's (probably) not an issue with a file in bridging header or something of that sort.

Also, if I replace `NSString` with `NSMutableData`, the problem persists, and the struct cannot be seen.

Comment: did you `import Foundation` ?

Comment: Good point, but yes. Foundation is imported when I'm defining this struct in `Foo.h` and in my destination `Bar.swift`

Comment: you know that you are conflicting `@available(OSX 10.12, iOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, tvOS 10.0, *) public struct Measurement<UnitType>`

Comment: @OlSen well spotted, but these names are all obfuscated versions of my code. I updated my question to reflect that better.

Comment: The problem you have is definitely not from `NSString* value` inside C struct. Structs in Swift are handled differently and are not compatible as is. The documentation talks only about similar syntax, not about about generated converting C structs to swift structs.

Comment: My question is "Why is one `typedef` visible from swift and the other one isn't".